# inserting a node at the end of linked list recursivly

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
typedef struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
}node;
void generate(struct node **head)
{
    int num = 10, i; //the num here is the length
    struct node *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->a = 10-i;
        if (*head == NULL)
        {
            *head = temp;  //each time add another node to the start
            (*head)->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = *head;
            *head = temp;
        }
    }
}
void addSpecific(node* head,int n)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*)); //allocating memory
        (temp)->a = n;  //adding the wanted value
        (temp)->next = NULL; //making the new node to point to the end
        head->next = temp; //and the previous one to point to temp
    }
    else
    {
        addSpecific(head->next, n); //if this is not the wanted node we need to move to the next node
    }
}
void deleteNode(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    while (*head != NULL)
    {
        temp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next; //going to the next node
        free(temp); //free the allocated memory
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    generate(&head);
    addSpecific(head, 7);
    display(head);
    deleteNode(&head);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to insert new node at the end using recursion, but the free memory (delete) function make an expansion, and I couldn't find the problem. I tried the generating function and adding the node at the end and it worked but the complier alert me for "heap corruption".

Comment: The assignment `head->next = &temp` does not do what you think it does. If you don't get a compiler warning from that line you need to enable more warnings. As for why it's wrong, think about what type `head->next` is,  what type is `temp`, and then lastly what type is `&temp`?

Comment: Not directly related, but using recursion here is a terrible idea.

Comment: that what my teacher told me, I had no choice

Comment: Also not related: instead of  writing `(temp)->a` you should write `temp->a` which is more standard, it's purely cosmetic, the generated code is the same.

Comment: @TalSokolinsky OK in that case, but you still should understand why recursion here is not a good idea and you could mention this on your homework copy.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: What is wrong with using recursion to traverse a linked data-structure? That's pretty standard, and some traversals of linked data-structures are *vastly* easier to write recursively.

Comment: Think about what happens if the list is a few thousands nodes long... All normal standard computers and compilers uses the stack for function calls, and the stack is a limited resource (default stack size on Windows using the Visual Studio compiler is a single megabyte).

Comment: @EOF in that case it's pure tail recursion and absolutely not necessary and not even easier. Now maybe the compiler optimizes this away. And if the optimizer doesn't optimize away the tail recursion, you also may run out of stack space, and it is less efficient.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I'd argue that this is fine precisely *because* the function is tail-recursive. If your compiler doesn't eliminate tail-recursion, you need to get a better compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void addSpecific( node **head, int n )
{
    if ( *head == NULL )
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( node ) ); //allocating memory
        ( *head )->a    = n;  //adding the wanted value
        ( *head )->next = NULL; //making the new node to point to the end
    }
    else
    {
        addSpecific( &( *head )->next, n ); //if this is not the wanted node we need to move to the next node
    }
}

void display( node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next ) printf( "%d ", head->a );
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    node *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        addSpecific( &head, i );

        display( head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As for the function `deleteNode` then it can look for example the following way

```
void deleteNode( node **head )
{
    for ( node *current = *head; current != NULL; )
    {
        node *temp  = current;
        current = current->next; //going to the next node
        free( temp ); //free the allocated memory
    }

    *head = NULL;
}
```

As for this implementation of the function

```
void deleteNode( node **head )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        node *temp  = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next; //going to the next node
        free( temp ); //free the allocated memory
    }
}
```

then it has undefined behavior because it tries to access a data member of the structure object that was already deleted.

Or you can make the function recursive. For example

```
void deleteNode( node **head )
{
    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        deleteNode( &( *head )->next );
        free( *head );
        *head = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the for in the display function? because I don't understand the way it works. and the out put was 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 when I compiled this code

Comment: @TalSokolinsky I think it is the simplest part of the shown code.:) The for loop just traverses the list until next node is equal to NULL. You could write the function as recursive.

Comment: @TalSokolinsky I think the loop will be more clear for you if you write for ( node *tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next ) printf( "%d ", tmp->a );

Comment: Why when I try to free the memory (by using the function deleteNode() in the question) it makes a heap corruption expansion and in your code it doesn't?

Comment: @TalSokolinsky You must write head = &( *head )->next;

Comment: where do I have to put it?

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, but it is quite convenient to maintain single-linked lists with two pointers, rather than one. This way you can prepend and append the list in `O(1)` without having to use recursion. E.g.:

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *head, **tail;
};

void List_init(struct List* list) {
    list->head = 0;
    list->tail = &list->head;
}

void List_append(struct List* list, struct Node* node) {
    node->next = 0;
    *list->tail = node;
    list->tail = &node->next;
}

void List_prepend(struct List* list, struct Node* node) {
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    if(list->tail == &list->head)
        list->tail = &node->next;
}

void List_remove(struct List* list, struct Node* node) {
    struct Node *cur = list->head, **prev = &list->head;
    while(cur && cur != node) {
        prev = &cur->next;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if(cur) {
        if(!(*prev = node->next))
            list->tail = prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I was asked to make a recursive function (by my teacher) but thanks for the iterative solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# For reference:
#
# SinglyLinkedListNode:
#     int data
#     SinglyLinkedListNode next


def insertNodeAtTail(node, data):
    if node is None:
        last = SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data=data)
        last.next = None
        return last
    
    if node.next is None:
        last = SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data=data)
        last.next = None
        node.next = last
        return node
    
    node.next = insertNodeAtTail(node.next, data)

    return node
```